# Jwt динамическое управление запросами

Tags: rest, безопасность, архитектура, jwt, микросервисы

### Я пытаюсь добиться хорошей архитектуры микросервисов.

**У меня есть  URI для авторизации /auth** и после авторизации **выдается JWT
есть NoSQL база данных.** Например Redis. Есть **endpoint /profil**. Но так как у меня noSQL решение в базе данных и микросервисная архитектура. Я не могу как то связать таблички пользователей напрямую. Иными словами.

**endpoint /profil хранит все профили пользователей мне нужно как то отличать различные запросы** В мою базу данных. Я придумал решение. **Шифровать ключи/указатели в JWT. При авторизации user будет получать JWT в котором будет ссылка на его персональную колекцию данных**. Иными словами при обращении к REST API, JWT будет расшифровываться и указывать на колекцию. Насколько это решение является  безопасным и обще принятым?

---

Comment: используйте обычную sql...

Comment: Я использую Node и SQL сожрет весь мой maib loop(поток) как минимум.

Comment: а... тогда я хз. Я не понимаю как можно микросервисы на ноде делать. тут я не помогу

Comment: Суть не в инструменте. Суть в noSQL и структуре REST.Я просто не очень понимаю насколько данное решение является  нормальным. Быть может я просто изобретаю велосипед.

Comment: Скорее всего да. С nosql не работал. Но разве нельзя в `endpoint /profil` указать просто `userId` какой-то? да, связи как в `sql` не будет, но за то проще доставать. В JWT загнать логин юзера, а потом по логину вытащить юзера из бд и по его id достать профиль

Comment: Я  это и хочу сделать. Но не понимаю нормальное ли это решение. Просто вдруг я изобретаю велосипед :D

Answer (score 0):

Да это нормальное поведение. При  сессиях все так же работает через cockies.